# iOS Loading big image crash

Tags: ios

I make a game on iOS, but on iPhone 4/4S, crash due to memory pression.

The Image is a map that the retina size its 4MB. I have it in two small parts (For design proposes), of 3MB and the other of 1MB.

I know they are kind-of big images but not enough to crash, the weird part its that when it loads on a UIImageView that loads on a UISCROLLVIEW it expands to 50MB (I check it with instruments).

on those phones, that its killing me, because if I consume more than 100MB apple kill the app, and its just the map, then I load the gameplay.

How can I handle this, why 4MB expands to 50MB. All my assets are 70MB (iPad, iPad Retina, iPhone & iPhone Retina)

Edit:

I have 2 posible solutions:

1-. Disable @2x on iPhone 4/4S (I don't know how to do this)

2-. Tiled the map in like 1000 small pieces of about 100px x 480px. and load it while the user it's scrolling?

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: In memory the loaded image will take up "4 x image width x image height" bytes. The size on disk is irrelevant.

Comment: @rmaddy and what can I do, there are 11K x 1K pixels

Comment: That's over 46MB of memory. That's huge. Perhaps you can tile the image. Do some searching on how to handle large images. I believe there is a sample app from Apple about tiling large images in a scroll view.

Comment: @rmaddy I see, I am searching, but the solution that apple gives, its too zoom the image and reloaded, but mine its a map, you can't zoom it,  I have two possible solution, I edit the question

Comment: Option 2 is what you want.

Comment: @rmaddy, and then when they go off-screen I eliminate them?